# TIFF image, tiff library for visual C++

Tags: visual-c++, tiff

I want to use tiff library in visual C++ for loading tiff image in the code.. but unable to do that.kindly suggest

Answer (score 3):

the most commonly used library would be [libtiff](http://www.libtiff.org/).

Comment: i m explaining what i m doing
1. extracted tiff 4.0.2
2. in vs 2008 x64 win 64 command prompt setting the environment for x86 by running vcvars32.bat
3.changing the path to tiff4.0.2/libtiff folder
4. Running nmake /f makefile.vc to create a static library of libtiff
then these errors comes into picture. I dnt know what goes wrong ...following these steps in windows XP generates the .lib file but in windows 7 it fails

This is the first time i m making any .lib so i m just a beginner

Comment: http://www.remotesensing.org/libtiff/build.html#PC says you need to have a built zlib and libjpeg (built with the same compiler!), or comment out the entries for  JPEG_SUPPORT, PIXARLOG_SUPPORT, and ZIP_SUPPORT in libtiff\tiffconf.h. Did you do that?

Answer (score -1):

I prefer convert the `tiff` image to png, then read as `png` by the lib `stb_image`.

It was too complex to build the libtiff with dependencies (like zlib, jpeg, etc.). But if you do not need to deal with deflation tiff file, I think config `libtiff` by NuGet is a much easier solution.

Comment: you'd better add more info about converting tiff->png with stb_image